# Java: How to replace last 16 bits of a long with a short

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a long and a short
I want the bits from the short to overwrite the low order 16 bits of the long.

Ex (broken into 16bit chunks for readability):

```
> long = 0xffff 0xffff 0xffff 0xffff
> short= 0x1234
> 
> output = (long)0xffff 0xffff 0xffff 0x1234
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
static long foobar(long aLong, short aShort) {
    return aLong & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF0000L | aShort & 0xFFFFL;
}
```

Note that you must AND the `short` value with `0xFFFFL` here, otherwise [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) will cause the code to break (all high bits in the result will be set, regardless of their original value in the `long`) if the `short` is greater than or equal to `0x8000`.

Answer (score 6):

```
long l = ...;
short s = ...;
long n = (l & ~0xFFFF) | (s & 0xFFFFL);
```

Comment: As currently written, this will break if `s >= 0x8000`, as Java will sign-extend `s` when it converts it from `short` to `long` to perform the bitwise OR. See also the edit I just made on my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I'll patch up mine too.